# SQL Server Stored Procedure Issue. Get Multiple result From Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, group-by

Here is my stored procedure to get a list of employees and their hours worked between `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_get_employeehourlyreport]
  @startdate  datetime,
  @enddate datetime
as 
begin
   select * 
   from (
      select 
         (select FullName from Registration 
          where Registration.UserId = UserTime.UserId) Fullname, 
         ISNULL(SUM(HoursWorked), 0) HoursWorked 
      from UserTime 
      where CheckIn between @startdate and @enddate
      group by UserId, CheckIn) tbl
end
```

The result I am getting is :

```
   Fullname             HoursWorked
   Antonio Jake         0
   Antonio Jake         0.016666
```

So basically it is displaying one row extra with hours 0. I Do not have any duplicate FullName in my database.

Table structures are:

`USERTIME`:

```
  UserTimeId    int             Unchecked
  UserId        int             Checked
  CheckIn       datetime        Checked
  LoginStatus   nvarchar(50)    Checked
  Day           varchar(50)     Checked
  HoursWorked   float           Checked
  Date          nvarchar(50)    Checked
```

`REGISTRATION`:

```
  UserId    int Unchecked
  FullName  varchar(50) Checked
```

Comment: Usertime is the table name. Please See first table . I have already mentioned it. And the query is running perfectly ecept it gives duplicate result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this....

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_get_employeehourlyreport]
@startdate  datetime,
@enddate datetime
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT R.FullName, ISNULL(SUM(UT.HoursWorked),0) AS Total_Hours 
    FROM Registration R LEFT JOIN USERTIME UT
    ON   R.UserId = UT.UserId                                                                                                                    Fullname ,ISNULL(SUM(HoursWorked),0) HoursWorked from UserTime 
    AND   UT.CheckIn >= @startdate 
    AND   UT.CheckIn <= @enddate
    GROUP BY R.FullName
END
```

Comment: It dos not compile. Gives error as "Incorrect syntax near 'Fullname'."

Comment: Can you not see any difference in my code and the code you have written ? Just copy paste this and it will work, you dont need to worry about NULLs when using SUM function. your Join syntax is bang out of order, just copy paste my solution and it will work. And also google `SUM` and `JOINS` in sql server.

Comment: I have also changed the INNER JOIN to left join which will return all the users even if they haven't worked at all with in the date range it will show their worked hours as `0`.

Comment: @M.Ali . . . It will behave as you describe it if you move the `where` conditions to the `on` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sir with due respect will it make any difference if the startdate and enddate is in `ON` clause or `WHERE` clause.

Comment: If you want a `left outer join` it makes a difference.  Your query now is effectively doing an `inner join`.